# Randomized incremental algorithm for linear optimization

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to figure out a randomized incremental algorithm for a huge bunch of equations (Around 60K). The function I'm attempting to create takes in the number of inequalities, the coefficient matrix and the right-hand side, and the coefficients of the objective function. What I wanted to ask is which would be the best algorithm that would work best as I've tried to do research to aid and I just can't seem to find one that would work.

Comment: You seem to be asking how to write a linear programming solver.  Writing an efficient one is a HUGE task, so don't -- use an existing one.

Comment: While I want to, my original idea was to try to use CPLEX since I heard of that in a lecture but I was wondering if CPLEX can be used to count the number of recomputations.

Comment: It's unclear whether you want CPLEX to count the number of "recomputations" (what are they?) needed to solve your problem, or to just *solve the actual problem*.

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to do both. the method I desired to create was to only output out an int value detailing the number of recomputations, while also inputting values of the result.